# How to check for internet connection repeatedly?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform, internet-connection

I am building an app using Swift and Parse. In several different `View Controllers`, I am using Parse to save and view objects. However, if I must have internet connection to access Parse. Currently, I have developed the following method to check for internet:

```
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://myeighthours.com/")

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        print(data)
        print(response)
        print(error)

        if let _ = data {

            UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()

            //Success


        } else {


            UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()

            //Failed

        }

    }

    task.resume()
```

Now this is in a separate `View Controller`. If I were to continuously check for internet, I would have to use this code in all of my view controllers every time I try to access Parse. This would be very tedious and inefficient. Also, I would have to 1. Create a segue to a separate "No Internet Connection" View Controller, or 2. Add a button to each View Controller saying "No Internet Connection. Tap to retry". If I turn off my internet connection and run the app, it simply stays there loading. I get this error message in my debug log:

```
2015-12-29 12:43:19.700 MYAPPNAME[975:354550] [Error]: The Internet connection appears to be offline. (Code: 100, Version: 1.7.5)
2015-12-29 12:43:19.700 MYAPPNAME[975:354550] [Error]: Network connection failed. Making attempt 2 after sleeping for 1.958450 seconds.
2015-12-29 12:43:21.854 MYAPPNAME[975:354549] [Error]: The Internet connection appears to be offline. (Code: 100, Version: 1.7.5)
2015-12-29 12:43:21.855 MYAPPNAME[975:354549] [Error]: Network connection failed. Making attempt 3 after sleeping for 3.916899 seconds.
2015-12-29 12:43:26.132 MYAPPNAME[975:354549] [Error]: The Internet connection appears to be offline. (Code: 100, Version: 1.7.5)
2015-12-29 12:43:26.133 MYAPPNAME[975:354549] [Error]: Network connection failed. Making attempt 4 after sleeping for 7.833799 seconds.
```

What is the most efficient way to repeatedly check for internet connection? Thanks for your help.

Comment: use a NStimer in which method check internet connection repeatedly, also define this method globally

Comment: Use Reachability.swift available at https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Best way to check for internet connection works and tested on Swift 2.0

1) Create a new swift file connection.swift and include this code below

```
import Foundation

        import SystemConfiguration

        public class Reachability {

            class func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool {

                var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in(sin_len: 0, sin_family: 0, sin_port: 0, sin_addr: in_addr(s_addr: 0), sin_zero: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
                zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(zeroAddress))
                zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

                let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(&zeroAddress) {
                    SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(kCFAllocatorDefault, UnsafePointer($0))
                }

                var flags: SCNetworkReachabilityFlags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags(rawValue: 0)
                if SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability!, &flags) == false {
                    return false
                }

                let isReachable = flags == .Reachable
                let needsConnection = flags == .ConnectionRequired

                return isReachable && !needsConnection

            }
        }
```

> You can use this method anywhere

```
 if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true {
                println("Internet connection OK")
            } else {
                println("Internet connection FAILED")
            }
            If the user is not connected to the internet, you may want to show them an alert dialog to notify them.
            if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true {
                println("Internet connection OK")
            } else {
                println("Internet connection FAILED")
                var alert = UIAlertView(title: "No Internet Connection", message: "Make sure your device is connected to the internet.", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                alert.show()
        }
```

> Took idea from

https://github.com/Isuru-Nanayakkara/Reach

Comment: Really nice and  neat

Answer (score -2):

```
#import <SystemConfiguration/SCNetworkReachability.h>
```

call isNetworkReachable method by NSTimer once you detect that Internet is not reachable to continuously check connectivity... timer repeat duration should be 2-3 second.Also your NStimer instance should be global not in every view controller

```
+(BOOL)isNetworkReachable
{
    SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags;
    SCNetworkReachabilityRef address;
    address = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(NULL, "www.google.com" );
    Boolean success = SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(address, &flags);
    CFRelease(address);

    bool canReach = success
    && !(flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsConnectionRequired)
    && (flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsReachable);

    return canReach;
}
```

Comment: Please make sure that your code works before you submit it. I get various error. Double check oyur coude.

Comment: I think you forgot to add systemConfiguration framework in your project... go to settings of project and in build settings add system configuration framwork in your project

Comment: Don't you just hate when people just to copy+paste code from SO and expect it to work, without at least trying to understand how the code works?

Comment: @penatheboss the example the OP gave is in `ObjectiveC`, likely this is why it gives compilation errors in your `Swift` file

Comment: I converted the code over to swift using objectivec2swift. Also, @Divyanshu Sharma never stated in his original answer to add the framework.